# c++ transfer a parameter to qsort comparer

Tags: c++, qsort

I am sorting custom objects, and as a comparer I have a function with random tie-breaking (this is important because I am calling it many times, and want a different order each time). This implies that I cannot use std::sort, because this comparer does not satisfy the requirement of strict weak ordering (because it does not maintain transitivity).

This can be done with qsort, but there I have another problem: I need to pass to the comparator function the random engine (e.g. m19937). I cannot use a global random engine, because of other reasons (it is called by multiple threads, and having a global variable makes the program non-deterministic). Transferring a parameter to the comparer function can solve my problem (I will transfer the random engine) - but I do not know how to transfer a parameter to the comparator. Is this possible ?
As far as I saw qsort cannot take a functor as a comparer.

Comment: `qsort` must return consistent results when called for the same objects. Implement your own sorting function - it's not rocket science, it's just boring.

Comment: You can use a stateful comparator which remembers how it broke ties with `std::sort`

Answer (score 6):

> I am sorting custom objects, and as a comparer I have a function with random tie-breaking

Then you cannot use `std::qsort`. C11 draft n1570 says:

> 7.22.5 Searching and sorting utilities
>
> When the same objects (consisting of size bytes, irrespective of their current positions in the array) are passed more than once to the comparison function, the results shall be consistent with one another. That is, for qsort they shall define a total ordering on the array, ...

---

> I cannot use a global random engine, because of other reasons (it is called by multiple threads, and having a global variable makes the program non-deterministic).

If this was the only problem, you might solve it by using thread local random engine.

---

A simple alternative to achieve the same thing: Shuffle the range first, then sort.

Comment: thread local is a great idea, thank you.
Do you know what happens if if I am violating the condition in the standard that you quoted is violated ? is it supposed to throw an exception ? I have been using it for a long time and nothing like this happened. I am running VS19.

Comment: @Oferstrichman violating such preconditions results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: in that case, are you aware of an implementation of a sorter with random tie-breaker ? seems like a useful tool to have. My search for 'c++ sort with a random tie-breaker' did not yield much.

Comment: @Oferstrichman I haven't used any. I added a simple alternative to the answer: Shuffle, then sort. That way you don't need random tie braking.

Answer (score 0):

As far as `qsort` is considered, I guess `qsort_s` will do the trick, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't specify `std::qsort_s`.